# I'm able to connect when Raspberry is connected via cable, but not via Wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I downloaded `2019-09-26-raspbian-buster.img` (3.7GB after extraction)

then I used `win32diskimager-1.0.0` to burn it on `MicroSD` card

then on `/boot/` I created

`ssh` file

`wpa_supplicant.conf` file

with content:

```
country=PL
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

network={ 
    ssid="MyHomeWifiSSID" 
    psk="p@ssw0rd" 
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
}
```

then in `cmdline.txt` I added

`ip=10.1.1.134::255.255.255.0`

but I'm unable to connect to my Raspberry via Wifi, but everything works fine via cable.

I tried also to scan network with `Angry Ip Scanner` but it doesn't show my Raspberry when it is on Wifi, but shows normally when it's connected via cable.

Configuration from: `wpa_supplicant.conf` seems to be applied correctly because file disappeared from `/boot/`

What can be wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What will the kernel command line option `ip=10.1.1.134::255.255.255.0` do? What network interface shall get this ip address? I'm not sure but as far as I know this option has no effect. Please edit your question and add the output of these two commands from the RasPi to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed WiFi (from router to phone) and it started working fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a different IP address for the Wired and the Wireless connections.
If you router sees a different MAC address on the WiFi than the Wired NIC it won't want to give the same IP address out until that DHCP lease has expired.

Answer (score 0):

If your router has bandwidth options you should try switching between 2.4 and 5ghz as my raspberry sometimes don't want to connect on one or the other.